# Problem in creating a new apple id

Tags: apple-id

I bought a second hand iphone 5s, I erase all content and settings, then i want to create my apple id, to download apps and all, i completed the procedure to create an apple id but at last the device showing me that "this device is no longer eligible for creating a free icloud account" how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Ask seller to delete device from his account on http://icloud.com Device should be erased and it will become free for new owner

Answer (score 0):

The previous owner should "Un-link" his/her icloud account from the device so you would be able to use it.

To erase all content and settings by choosing *Settings > General > Reset > Erase All Content and Settings*. OR from the icloud account online.... Then his/her Apple ID and password needed. After the device is erased, you will be able to proceed with the setup process.